# Is a "drive-by-download" site liable for their content

Tags: hacking

There was an incident where forbes.com was delivering viruses through Javascript exploits found in their ads. This happened just by clicking a link (before you can "agree" to anything).

Are they liable under anti-hacking regulations?

What about ad networks?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, but I very much doubt they would be liable, as they did not commit the hacking themselves.   The ad networks are in a grey area - it really depends on if they were turning a blind eye (and, were it to go to court, you would have to prove it, which would prove difficult).